# Need to Set Default headers for all http requests

Tags: java, android, header

My app uses a 3rd party client to connect to a server. It offers an api for entering a user/pass. Unfortunately, the server we need to connect to also requires additional fields in the headers.

This client api hides its underlying HttpsURLConnection instance, so we can't set any headers.

`HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultRequestProperty()` would have solved my issue, but it is now deprecated.

Is there an alternative method to set headers on a global level?

Comment: unfortunately the javadocs suggest the preferred approach is to set this on spacific instances of url connections. assumming they really dont provide any APIs, have you considered something more invasive?

Comment: Which library are you using? Don't they provide anything to do more low level stuff?

Comment: The client is the [Lightstreamer android client.]
(http://www.lightstreamer.com/docs/client_android_api/index.html) 
I have confirmed on their forums that you can't modify the headers.

Comment: @radai could you explain "more invasive" options?

Comment: @PatrickLocke - reflection. nothing in java is really inaccessible, if youre willing to work hard enough. having said that, this is an absolute last resort :-)

Comment: If I understood you question correctly you have problem with default implementation of httpsurlconnection. Try using Retrofit.

Comment: @radai - Unfortuanely, reflection is quite error prone since developers can change stuff at any time...

Comment: @ToonBorgers - yup. also slow. this is why i said last resort. if its reflection or nothing however ...

Comment: I'm not seeing how reflection would work. I'm guessing there is a method in this compiled library somewhere which creates the HttpsURLConnection, fires it off, and disposes of it.

Answer (score 0):

> This client api hides its underlying HttpsURLConnection instance, so we can't set any headers.

If the library is open source, modify it to add your headers.

If the library is not open source, you do not really know whether they are using `HttpsUrlConnection` or something else (e.g., HttpClient).

> Is there an alternative method to set headers on a global level?

Not in a way that somehow works across all possible HTTP client APIs, including hand-rolling an HTTP client using raw sockets.

You are also welcome to create your own Lightstream client ("The network protocol used by Lightstreamer is fully documented, so that you can directly develop your own client applications based on any other language and platform").